# How to send data to antoher class

Tags: java, android, firebase

How can I change textview in another class with storageCointainer method? I want to get data from storageCointainer method to change textview in HomeFragment class.

```
public void getSavedMoney() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String money = ds.child("saveMoney").getValue().toString();
                moneyStringList.add(money);
            }
            moneyNumList = Lists.transform(moneyStringList, Double::parseDouble);
            savedMoney = moneyNumList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
            storageContainer(savedMoney);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}

public void storageContainer(double savedMoney) {
    this.savedMoney = savedMoney;
}
```

Comment: Use the callback pattern. `HomeFragment` should implement an interface that has a method for passing back your data. `storageContainer` should then call `HomeFragment`'s instance of that method, which should in turn update your `TextView`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value by using `Bundle`. You can refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/9245510/9346054

For you case, you can create the instance like below.

```
public static HomeFragment newInstance(final Double savedMoney) {
    final HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    final Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putDouble("savedMoney", savedMoney);
    homeFragment.setArguments(args);
    return homeFragment;
}
```

Next, implement it at the `storageContainer` method like this.

```
public void storageContainer(double savedMoney) {
    this.savedMoney = savedMoney;
    newInstance(savedMoney);
}
```

At the `HomeFragment`, you can get the value at `onCreate`. Example as below

```
final Double savedMoney = getArguments().getDouble("savedMoney", 0);
//Display at the textView
tvSavedMoney.setText("Total: " + savedMoney);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send the value `savedMoney` to another activity, you should consider sending it [only when it's ready](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774). A typical way of sending the data would be through an [Intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent). So in code should look like this:

```
public void getSavedMoney() {
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String money = ds.child("saveMoney").getValue().toString();
                moneyStringList.add(money);
            }
            moneyNumList = Lists.transform(moneyStringList, Double::parseDouble);
            savedMoney = moneyNumList.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).sum();
            //storageContainer(savedMoney); // removed

            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras("savedMoney", savedMoney);
            startActivity(intent);            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("TAG", error.getMessage()); //Never ignore potential errors!
        }
    });
}
```

And to get it back inside the next activity, simply use:

```
double savedMoney = getIntent().getExtras().getDouble("savedMoney");
Log.d("TAG", "savedMoney = " + savedMoney);
```

If you understand Kotlin, I recommend you read the following resource:

- [How to read data from Firebase Realtime Database using get()?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5)

Where I have explained **three** ways in which we can get data from [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) using the [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query#get()) method.

Comment: Hey Artur. Have you tried my solution above? Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If both your activities are not directly related, you can try to use BroadcastManager to send intents across.